# Create a column containing specific string expressions derived from another column

Tags: r

In a dataframe, I would like to create a column out of an existing one. The new column (name="Symbol") should contain only a subset of the expressions found on the existing column (name="Description) based on a matching pattern, which in my case is defined by the prefix `GN=`. For those cells missing the matching pattern from the existing column, "Not available" should be returned in the new column. From here:

```
View(df[,1:3])

Accession   Description                                                                               Sample1
A0FGR9      Extended synaptotagmin-3 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ESYT3 PE=1 SV=1 - [ESYT3_HUMAN]               117.920
A6NHJ4      Zinc finger protein 860 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ZNF860 PE=1 SV=3 - [ZN860_HUMAN]               30.218
A0A0C4DH68  Immunoglobulin kappa variable 2-24 OS=Homo sapiens GN=IGKV2-24 PE=3 SV=1 - [KV224_HUMAN]  524.706
P0DOX7      Immunoglobulin kappa light chain OS=Homo sapiens PE=1 SV=1 - [IGK_HUMAN]                  503.110
```

I would like to get here:

```
View(df[,1:4])

Accession   Description                                                                               Symbol          Sample1
A0FGR9      Extended synaptotagmin-3 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ESYT3 PE=1 SV=1 - [ESYT3_HUMAN]               ESYT3           117.920
A6NHJ4      Zinc finger protein 860 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ZNF860 PE=1 SV=3 - [ZN860_HUMAN]               ZNF860          30.218
A0A0C4DH68  Immunoglobulin kappa variable 2-24 OS=Homo sapiens GN=IGKV2-24 PE=3 SV=1 - [KV224_HUMAN]  IGKV2-24        524.706
P0DOX7      Immunoglobulin kappa light chain OS=Homo sapiens PE=1 SV=1 - [IGK_HUMAN]                  Not available   503.110
```

Thank you in advance for the fruitful suggestions.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(h=T,strin=F,text="
Accession   Description                                                                               Sample1
A0FGR9      'Extended synaptotagmin-3 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ESYT3 PE=1 SV=1 - [ESYT3_HUMAN]'               117.920
A6NHJ4      'Zinc finger protein 860 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ZNF860 PE=1 SV=3 - [ZN860_HUMAN]'               30.218
A0A0C4DH68  'Immunoglobulin kappa variable 2-24 OS=Homo sapiens GN=IGKV2-24 PE=3 SV=1 - [KV224_HUMAN]'  524.706
P0DOX7      'Immunoglobulin kappa light chain OS=Homo sapiens PE=1 SV=1 - [IGK_HUMAN]'                  503.110
")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following `regex`

```
df$symbol = sub(".*GN=(.*?) .*","\\1",df$Description)
```

Then correct for nonmatches

```
df$symbol[df$symbol==df$Description] = "Not available"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package *unglue* :

```r
# install.packages("unglue")
library(unglue)
df <- unglue_unnest(df, Description, "{=.*?} GN={Symbol} {=.*?}", remove = FALSE)
df$Symbol[is.na(df$Symbol)] <- "Not available"
df
#>    Accession
#> 1     A0FGR9
#> 2     A6NHJ4
#> 3 A0A0C4DH68
#> 4     P0DOX7
#>                                                                                Description
#> 1              Extended synaptotagmin-3 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ESYT3 PE=1 SV=1 - [ESYT3_HUMAN]
#> 2              Zinc finger protein 860 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ZNF860 PE=1 SV=3 - [ZN860_HUMAN]
#> 3 Immunoglobulin kappa variable 2-24 OS=Homo sapiens GN=IGKV2-24 PE=3 SV=1 - [KV224_HUMAN]
#> 4                 Immunoglobulin kappa light chain OS=Homo sapiens PE=1 SV=1 - [IGK_HUMAN]
#>   Sample1        Symbol
#> 1 117.920         ESYT3
#> 2  30.218        ZNF860
#> 3 524.706      IGKV2-24
#> 4 503.110 Not available
```

More info : https://github.com/moodymudskipper/unglue/blob/master/README.md